# Are all Java apps single-threaded unless the programmer explicitly creates Threads or implementations of Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, thread-safety

I'm trying to understand how Java (and the JVM) create threads under the hood.

I read Java Concurrency in Practice, and I couldn't find a good explanation of whether or not all Java apps are, by default, single- or multi-threaded.

On the one hand, from the POV of a developer: I write a pile of sequential code without creating Thread instances or implementing Runnable anywhere. Do I need to synchronize anything? Should I be making double-sure my classes are thread-safe? If so, should I stop using POJOs that have mutable fields? I read that the JVM will create multiple threads under the hood for its own business. Is the JVM also creating threads to run my application without me explicitly creating those threads?

On the other hand: I write a pile of code in which I explicitly create Threads and Runnable implementations. Does the JVM spin off its own threads to "help" my multi-threaded code run faster?

It's entirely possible I'm not even thinking about the JVM's thread handling in the right way. But, I'm an entry-level Java developer, and I hate that I find this confusing.

Comment: Lots of APIs create threads under the hood: AWT, Swing, RMI, Async I/O, ... There are also built-in threads like the finalizers these that call your code, and the GC thread(s) that don't, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On the one hand, from the POV of a developer: I write a pile of sequential code without creating Thread instances or implementing
>   Runnable anywhere. Do I need to synchronize anything? Should I be
>   making double-sure my classes are thread-safe? If so, should I stop
>   using POJOs that have mutable fields?

The straightforward answer is that **no, you do not need to proactively make your objects thread-safe to protect them from concurrent access by threads you did not create.**

Generally speaking, threads that interact concurrently with the code and classes you write<sup>1</sup> won't be be created unless you do something yourself that is known to create threads, and then you organize to share an object instance between threads. Creating a `Thread` object is one example of creating a thread, but there are others. Here is a non-exhaustive list:

- Using `Executor` or `ExecutorService` implementations which use threads (most of them).
- Use a concurrent `Stream` method e.g., by creating a stream with the `parallelStream` method.
- Use a library method which creates threads behind the scenes.

So generally threads don't just pop out of nowhere but rather as a result of something you do. Even if a library creates threads that you don't know about, it doesn't matter for your concern because unless documented otherwise they will *not be accessing your objects, or will use locking to ensure they access them in a serialized fashion* (or the library is seriously broken).

So you generally don't need to worry about cross-thread synchronization except in places where you know threads are being used. So by default you don't need to make your objects thread-safe.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm making this distinction about "interact with code you write" because a typical JVM will use several threads behind the scenes, even if you never create any yourself, for housekeeping tasks like garbage collection, calling finalizers, listening for JMX connections, whatever.

Comment: The finalizer thread interact with code that you write, as does `UnicastRemoteObject`.

Comment: I really appreciate the level of detail you provided. But what confuses me is that, in the interest of safety for example, should I _never_ again have `int` fields, and only have `AtomicInteger`s? Because what if some dependency I'm using is creating threads in the background?

Comment: @LucasHenry - maybe my answer wasn't clear enough: you don't have to make things thread safe in general, because only the threads _you create yourself_ will generally touch your objects in an observable way. So yes, you should almost always have `int` fields, not `AtomicInteger` fields. You have full control over whether your objects will be accessed by multiple threads, and the vast majority of objects never have to be thread-safe.

Comment: @LucasHenry your confusion sounds like the same mistake the original Java designers made when sprinkling `synchronized` all over the Java 1.0 API. Making things “thread safe” on that low level doesn’t solve semantic issues, concurrent code may have (like the “check-then-act” anti-pattern, e.g. when using `if(!x.contains(y)) x.add(y);`, it doesn’t matter whether `x` is thread safe). On the other hand, when solving the semantic issues by designing correct concurrent application logic, synchronizing every low-level operation becomes obsolete, misleading, and just hindering performance.

Comment: @BeeOnRope That completely answers my question. I'd upvote your comment twice if I could

Comment: @user207421 - good point, finalizers do access your object, but at least they do it when the object is unreachable, so it shouldn't be problematic from a concurrency point of view (although of course if you try hard enough you can screw things up, e.g., re-publishing a reference to an unreachable finalizable object from within the finalizer). I've updated the text to make it clearer that the criterion is "interact concurrently" rather than just "interact".

Comment: @BeeOnRope actually, the definition of reachability can bear many surprises, so if you use a finalizer, you better synchronize it with the previous uses of the object, to enforce an ordering between the object’s last use and the finalization. That’s why JDK 9 introduced [`reachabilityFence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-) to be able to enforce reachability without thread synchronization (a typical use case would be an immutable object encapsulating a native resource).

Comment: @Holger - well I learning something new about finalizers today, pretty nasty stuff. It seems borderline obscure though - do you think I should mention it in this answer? Making your objects thread-safe won't help here, it's kind of an orthogonal concern.

Comment: Well, making it thread safe using `synchronized` would help, if `finalize()` uses `synchronized` too, but other means of thread safety, like the already mentioned immutability won’t prevent premature finalization (it may actually encourage it), so it’s orthogonal in hat case. You may add a note that finalization may imply multi-threading amongst other nasty problems and should not be used at all (`finalize()` has been deprecated in Java 9 for all the problems it causes).

Answer (score 1):

Is the app code you wrote single- or multi-threaded? Unless you explicitly took steps to create new threads – for example, by doing something like `Thread t = new Thread();` – your app code will be single-threaded.

Are there multiple threads running in a single JVM? Yes, always – there will be various things running in the background that have nothing to do with the code you wrote (like the garbage collector).

Should you guard against concurrency concerns? With a single-threaded app, there is no need. However, if your code itself creates one (or more) threads, or if your code is packaged up in some manner to be used by other app creators (maybe you've created a data structure for others to use in their code), then you *might* need to take steps for concurrency correctness. In the case of creating code for others to use, it's perfectly fine to declare in Javadoc that your code is not threadsafe. For example, `ArrayList` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says *"Note that this implementation is not synchronized"* along with suggested workarounds.